# Critique my proof of: $A \times (B \cap C) = (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Critique my proof on correctness, structure, etc.

*Proof.* Suppose $p = (x,y)$ is an arbitrary element.

($\subseteq$)
Let $p \in A \times (B \cap C)$. By definition of cartesian product, $x \in A$ and $y \in B \cap C$. Thus, $y \in B$, $y \in C$ and $p \in (A \times B)$, $p \in (A \times C)$. By definition of $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$, $\ p \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ and because $p$ is arbitrary, we can say that $A \times (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$.

($\supseteq$)
Let $p \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$. Thus, $p \in (A \times B)$ and $p \in (A \times C)$. By definition of cartestian product, $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, $y \in C$. By definition of $A \times (B \cap C)$, $\ p \in A \times (B \cap C)$ and because $p$ is arbitrary, we can say that $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) \subseteq A \times (B \cap C)$.

$\therefore$ $A \times (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ and $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) \subseteq A \times (B \cap C)$, so $A \times (B \cap C) = (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$.

Comment: You have to take some p in each case. So the global p = (x, y) is not in its place especially since it is not necessarily an element of the same set (this has not yet been demonstrated)
In the second part, let $p\in (A\times B)\cap (A\times C)$. there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $p=(a,b)$ and there exists $a'\in A$ and $c\in C$ such that $p=(a',c)$. By def of =, a=a' and b=c.

Comment: Last remark, you place on the same line p belongs and the conclusion of the inclusion: "$\ p \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ and because $p$ is arbitrary, we can say that $A \times (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$" which gives the impression that the inclusion results from this belonging whereas it is deduced from the preceding reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first issue that seems minor, but causes all sorts of confusion:  don't use commas as connectives; they often mean 'and' but sometimes mean 'if, then' and sometimes even mean 'or', and you'll get in the habit of reading them one way and not even notice when someone else uses (or you use!) them differently.  Thus, say not "$y \in B$, $y \in C$" but "$y \in B$ and $y \in C$", and similarly elsewhere.

I think you ought not to start with "Suppose $p = (x, y)$ is an arbitrary element"; arbitrary elements (of what?) are not ordered pairs.  Indeed, unless you work with an explicit universal set, then you ought not to fix $p$ outside of the case distinction at all.  In case ($\subseteq$) you fix $p$, observe that by the definition of $A \times (B \cap C)$ we have that $p$ is of the form $(x, y)$ for some $x \in A$ and $y \in B \cap C$, and then proceed as before.  Similarly for the other case (except that you have to wait a bit longer).

Otherwise your argument looks fine to me, depending on the level of detail expected.  For example, as an instructor, I might ask you to explain why $p \in A \times B$ and $p \in A \times C$ by appealing to the definitions there.

Comment: So, instead of starting the proof with "*Proof.* Suppose $p = (x,y)$ is an arbitrary element.", would it be okay to just start the proof with the $(\subseteq)$ case and begin it like "Let $p = (x,y)$ where $x \in A$ and $y \in B \cap C$"?

Comment: In all such matters, it depends on the level; but, at the level of first proofs in set theory, I would prefer to see everything justified by appeal to definition.  For the ($\subseteq$) case, you may only assume that you start with an element $p$ of $A \times (B \cap C)$; and it is only by analysing the definition of $A \times (B \cap C)$ that you realise that $p$ is of the form $(x, y)$ with $x \in A$ and $y \in B \times C$.  You need not be in too much of a hurry to destructure $p$!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to solve this kind of exercise by making use of the definitions and properties involved:
\begin{align*}
A\times(B\cap C) & = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in B\cap C)\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in B)\wedge(y\in C)\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(x\in A)\wedge (y\in B)\wedge(y\in C)\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid ((x\in A)\wedge (y\in B))\wedge((x\in A)\wedge(y\in C))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in B)\}\cap\{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in C)\}\\\\
& = (A\times B)\cap(A\times C)
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Do we have to say $$\{(x, y) \ \vert \ (x \in A) \land (x \in A) \land (y \in B) \land (y \in C)\}$$
or is it also acceptable to leave out the extra $(x \in A)$?

Comment: If you leave out the 'extra' $x \in A$, then it is not clear how you can re-associate to $((x \in A) \land (y \in B)) \land ((x \in A) \land (y \in C))$.